# Access data from FUSE filesystem

Tags: fuse

Is there any way that I can access the data created by my FUSE filesystem process?
e.g.
in prefix_write() I store some data in memory and would like to access those data from another process.

Shared memory should work. But I'm looking for a more elegant solution, such as a custom field in fuse_operations that I access as a function from other processes. But as far as I know, the fields in fuse_operations need to be from POSIX, so it's probably impossible to do so. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other process that you are speaking of, is it a process forked by another process. If yes then it should be pretty easy to send data. Before forking create a pipe and then fork, so the fd's returned by the pipe are inherited by the child process. You can then use these fd's for bi-directional data transfer.

If your use case is not this, then can you illustrate why do you want a foreign process to access another processes data?